# How should I refactor this code for posting a UIImage from a URL string? iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

This is probably a simple fix, but I'm new to this.

```
 NSString *barImageURLString = barDic[@"image_url"];
    NSURL *barImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:barImageURLString];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:barImageURL];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Update the UI
            cell.barImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        });
    });

    NSString *ratingImageURLString = barDic[@"rating_img_url"];
    NSURL *ratingImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:ratingImageURLString];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:ratingImageURL];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Update the UI
            cell.ratingImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        });
    });
```

Not sure how I would go about that with the dispatch_async in there.

Comment: It works fine, I just feel it can be refactored a bit. And what do you mean about the lack of ^{? They are there.

Comment: Doh, sorry about that. It was perfectly cut off and I didn't realize it was scrollable. I'll post an answer with proper error checking.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a POST not just a refactor of your code, which has the GET operation buried in `dataWithContentsOfURL:`.  Here's more general POST code...

```
NSData *data = // init this to the data that you want to post
NSString *someURLString = @"http://www.myservice.com/mypost.php";
NSURL = *url = [NSURL URLWithString:someURLString];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
// depends on the data, but something like this to set a header...
[request setValue:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

request.HTTPBody = data;

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {

    }
}];
```

This can be refactored into a GET by replacing the mutable url request with an immutable request and optionally adding query parameters to the url string.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works under ideal conditions, but you want to do some error checking to prevent runtime exceptions.

```
NSString *barImageURLString = barDic[@"image_url"];
    NSURL *barImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:barImageURLString];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:barImageURL];
        // check for valid data
        if ( imageData ) {
            // create the UIImage first and make sure it is a valid image
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            if ( image ) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // It is possible that your tableview cell is no longer on screen, check
                    YourTableViewCell *cellBeingUpdated = (id)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                    if ( cellBeingUpdated ) {
                        // Update the UI
                        cellBeingUpdated.barImageView.image = image;
                    }
                });
            }
       }
    });
```

Same applies to your other image. You want to have some sort of default image in case this fails. What I do is have a default image that I assign to the tableview cell before making the image request. This prevents blank imageviews while waiting for the actual image loading.

Comment: okay thanks. It just seemed like I was rewriting a lot of the same code to update two UIImages. Should I make a helper method for each image?

Comment: I know it seems like a lot, but the bulk is just checking for nil. You could definitely create the request and image creation into a function. You could pass the url to the function and it returns an image or nil. But you'll still have to check for a nil image and check for the tableview cell. You'll also want to implement some sort of caching as well. As it is now, this code will make a new request every time.

Answer (score 0):

Since the logic of fetching the image and doing something with it is mostly the same, and you don't want to repeat the code everytime a new kind of image needs to be loaded, you can create a function or method to do the repetitive work. The input to the function will be a URL to an image, and the output will be the image itself. Since the actual fetch will be asynchronous, the function can take in as input a block of code with instructions on what to do once the image is available. The block can also be notified of failures if the image could not be fetched for some reason.

```
- (void)fetchImageFromURL:(NSURL *)imageURL completionHandler:(void(^)(UIImage *image, NSError *error))completionHandler {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        NSError *error = ...; // do error handling if image load fails
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), completionHandler(imageData, error);
    });
}
```

This can be invoked as:

```
NSString *barImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:barDic[@"image_url"]];
[self fetchImageFromURL:barImageURL completionHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        // handle error
    }
    else {
        cell.barImageView.image = image;
    }
}];
```

Although it only seems to be cutting down a few lines of repetitive code, this design allows your code to be more flexible and scalable. This hides the implementation detail of how the image is actually fetched. Maybe you want to replace it with an asynchronous NSURLConnection, or with NSURLSession. This design allows for that kind of modifications without impacting the API. Error handling can be kept in a single place. Network requests can fail for a variety of reasons with the topmost reason being bad or no connectivity. You can add retry logic for such failures within the `-fetchImageFromURL:` method again without impacting the method API and callers. Maybe there is some caching you've built so there's no need to go out to the network at all. Again, this design would allow for such a growth.

In the most general terms, you want to separate the "what" from the "how". The `what` here is the image that some part of your code needs but it shouldn't concern itself with `how` that image is retrieved.